# Add (populate) multiple dynamic fields trough a url query

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

So I'm using gravity forms to let users send a form where the can ask for a sample product. They do this by clicking an image from an image gallery. At this point, I'm able to create a URL to the form and add /form/?parameter=value so I can add this value to a particular field. My problem is I need to fill 2 field values. At this point, I can find a way to create a URL that can be used to populate two fields.

I tried something like:

```
/form/?parameter=value?parameter2=value2
```

and

```
/form/?parameter=value&?parameter2=value2
```

Is this just not possible or am I looking for a wrong thing here?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: try by remove second **?**,just use **&**  so url like  **/form/?parameter=value&parameter2=value2**

Comment: Nerer replied but it worked like a charm. Can't figure out why I didn't try that. Thanx